# Edge of undirected graph in Java

Tags: java, graph, equals

Suppose I am writing a Java class to represent an edge of undirected graph. This class `Edge` contains two vertices `to` and `from`.

```
class Edge<Vertex> {

  private final Vertex to, from

  public Edge(Vertex to, Vertex from) {
    this.to = to;
    this.from = from;
  } 
  ... // getters, equals, hashCode ...
}
```

Obviously `e1 = new Edge(v1, v2)` and `e2 = new Edge(v2, v1)` are actually the same in an undirected graph. Does it make sense? How would you implement class `Edge` to meet that requirement?

Comment: Do you want to use this one implementation for both a directed edge and an undirected edge? I would reconsider that.

Answer (score 2):

Perform a sort on the vertices in the constructor based on some unique identifier.  This way they are stored consistently regardless of order.

I find this preferable to noMAD's solution because all code interacting with these objects will treat them identically, not just your implementation of `equals`.

Also, calling your class members `to` and `from` is confusing because it sounds like a directed graph.  I would rename these to something more generic like `vertex1` and `vertex2`.

```
  public Edge(Vertex x, Vertex y) {
      if (vertex2.getId() > vertex1.getId()) {
          this.vertex1 = x;
          this.vertex2 = y;
      } else {
          this.vertex1 = y;
          this.vertex2 = x;
      }
  }
```

Comment: I like this solution but it assumes that `Vertex` has some comparable `Id`. However graph in math does not assume that.

Answer (score 2):

I actually wouldn't have this logic in my `Edge` class but rather some sort of over-seeing class such as a `Graph` class. The reason for this is because an `Edge` is just an object with 2 vertices. It doesn't know anything about the rest of the edges in the graph.

So, to expand on @noMad's answer, I would actually put his `checkIfSameEdge` method in my `Graph` class:

```
public class Graph {
    private List<Edge> edges;
    ....
    public void addEdge(Edge e) {
        for (Edge edge : edges) {
            if (isSameEdge(edge, e) {
                return; // Edge already in Graph, nothing to do
        }
        edges.add(e);
    }
    private boolean isSameEdge(Edge edge1, Edge edge2) {
        return ((edge1.to.equals(edge2.to) && edge1.from.equals(edge2.from))
             || (edge1.to.equals(edge2.from) && edge1.from.equals(edge2.to)))
    }
}
```

BTW: I would rename `to` and `from` to `vertex1` and `vertex2` because it is an undirected graph and to and from indicate direction, but that's just my opion.

Answer (score 1):

Well, of the top of my head, the naivest method would be:

```
protected boolean checkIfSameEdge(Vertex to, Vertex from) {
  if(to.equals(this.from) && from.equals(this.to) || to.equals(this.to) && from.equals(this.from)) {
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

Obviously you would have to override `equals` and `hashcode`

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the nodes contain some sort of scalar values - sort the parameters based on these values (using the compareTo method) and use a factory to create a new instance or return an existing instance.